Ubuntu 20.04 Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/source/Sources'
Installing Mysql in my ubuntu machine that is 20.04 following this documentation
after downloading the deb package
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.30-1_all.deb

installed successfully but after
$ sudo apt-get update

returns
Hit:1 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                      
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                              
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                  
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [128 kB]                             
Hit:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease                                              
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                       
Hit:8 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro InRelease                                       
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                    
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                    
Ign:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0 InRelease      
Hit:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0 Release        
Hit:13 https://packages.redis.io/deb focal InRelease                            
Get:14 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0 Release.gpg [866 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [980 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [3332 kB]               
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1189 kB]             
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [786 kB]               
Hit:19 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/6.4/ubuntu /bionic InRelease                                  
Fetched 6416 kB in 2s (3000 kB/s)               
Reading package lists... Done
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/source/Sources' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'mysql-8.4-lts' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

at first ignored the W: Skipping acquire of configured file but after when tried to install mysql benchmark with command
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench-community

that seems to be related with the previous update command at least for me, but in my /etc/apt/sources.list can't find any reference of mysql with grep tried adding the following line

deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease

but didn't fix the sudo apt-get update
any solution for this how to install mysql-workbench-community and solve source.list error/warning messages?
